# pushViewController for once

Tags: swift, xcode

I have one `UIButton` which called `Get Started` in the welcome screen, by clicking on this button it will goes to the `PhoneNumberViewController` to type and click on the next button. For new users it will require to fill out some personal information in the `ProfileViewController` before going to the `HomeViewController`. Now I am struggling how can I pop that profile for once since I do not need registered users to check their information when they logout and re-login later.

Here is my code :

```
    private func checkUser(userId: String) {
    userService.getUser(Uid: userId) { (tutor) in
        if let user = user,
            !user.name.isEmpty && !user.email.isEmpty {
            Router.route(to: .home)
        } else {
            let profileViewController = UIStoryboard.main.viewController(of: ProfileViewController.self)
            profileViewController.isFromOnboarding = true
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only want to prevent the pushing of the view controller in the code above if it has been pushed once already?  Is that correct?

Comment: yes correct :) thank you for asking

Comment: It's not clear if you mean once ever or once in a particular app session.  If the user closes the app do you need to persist whether the profile was displayed any previous times?

Answer (score 1):

You can save a value in userDefault

```
private func checkUser(userId: String) {
let isPresented =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isPresented")
    userService.getUser(Uid: userId) { (tutor) in
        if let user = user,
            !user.name.isEmpty && !user.email.isEmpty {
            Router.route(to: .home)
        } else if !isPresented {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isPresented")
            let profileViewController = UIStoryboard.main.viewController(of: ProfileViewController.self)
            profileViewController.isFromOnboarding = true
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i hope it will help :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Create a `hasPushedProfile` flag in the controller which can be used to check if the profile view has already been shown or not.  On the first time through the flag will be `false` and will then be set to be `true` when the profile is displayed, next time through the profile will not display and you can do something else instead.

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

    static var hasPushedProfile = false

    private func checkUser(userId: String) {
        userService.getUser(Uid: userId) { (tutor) in
            if let user = user,
                !user.name.isEmpty && !user.email.isEmpty {
                Router.route(to: .home)
            } else {
                if hasPushedProfile == false {
                    hasPushedProfile = true
                    let profileViewController = UIStoryboard.main.viewController(of: ProfileViewController.self)
                    profileViewController.isFromOnboarding = true
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
                } else {
                    // Already pushed profile, do something else...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: each time when `LoginController` initialise... it will set `hasPushedProfile` to false ... and user will routes to  `ProfileViewController` ...

Comment: You can make it a static property that will retain it's value even it it's initialized again, see the edit.  Are you trying to display it once per app session, or only once no matter how many times the app is launched?

Comment: i think he is trying to display it once lifeTime .... not sure ...

Comment: Yes Jawad you are correct for only once lifetime, I will test your code today and let you know :)

Comment: @YasserAdel In that case then jawadAli's answer is what you're looking for.  Something to keep in mind for future questions, it is helpful to provide as many relevant details as possible.  While the details might seem obvious to the person asking the question, it isn't always so apparent from an outside perspective.  Please don't take this as criticism but give the '[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' guidelines a read as it is of benefit to both asking and answering questions on the site.